# Compiling Gnu11 for Windows with MinGW on Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc

I have a C program; it compiles and links with `gcc -std=gnu11 iter.c -o iter` because I am using some GNU `string.h` extensions like `strndup`, `strnlen` and `strsep`.

I want to compile this program for Windows using the package `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` on Ubuntu Linux.

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -std=gnu11 iter.c -o iter32.exe 
In file included from iter.c:1:0:
iter.h: In function ‘str_chomp’:
iter.h:166:15: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strndup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   char* new = strndup(str, MAX_STR_LEN);
               ^
iter.h:166:15: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strndup’
iter.h: In function ‘str_split’:
iter.h:189:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strndup’
       *str_copy = strndup(str, MAX_STR_LEN);
                   ^
iter.h:211:26: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strsep’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     for (i = 0; (token = strsep(&str_copy, delim_str)) != NULL; i++) {
                          ^
iter.h:211:24: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     for (i = 0; (token = strsep(&str_copy, delim_str)) != NULL; i++) {
                        ^
/tmp/ccPH0nG5.o:iter.c:(.text+0x216): undefined reference to `strndup'
/tmp/ccPH0nG5.o:iter.c:(.text+0x2bf): undefined reference to `strndup'
/tmp/ccPH0nG5.o:iter.c:(.text+0x3a7): undefined reference to `strsep'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have installed all the required MinGW runtime and libraries, but MinGW seems to ignore the `-std=gnu11` directive. It's not ignoring the option entirely, because `-std=asdf` is "unrecognised", but it refuses to cross-compile GNU C.

Is there a way I can cross-compile for Windows a program using GNU extensions?

Comment: If you're compiling a program that relies on Microsoft's C runtime library, as MinGWin programs do, then you are limited to the functions provided by that library.  You should be thankful that the compiler is telling you about this, instead of building a program destined to crash at runtime.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Isn't MinGW "Minimalist GNU for Windows"? Indeed, it's **GCC**, and GNU's LibC linked with GCC, so one would expect that the headers are GNU.

Comment: MinGW provides many GNU *programs*, including GCC, running natively on Windows.  It does *not* provide the GNU C library, relying instead on Microsoft's.  It relies on some other Windows system libraries as well.  This is clearly [documented](http://www.mingw.org/), and it makes sense.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well okay, silly misunderstanding aside, my question of "How do I compile GNU C for Windows?" still holds.

Comment: This is a very old thread but I just wanted to clarify. It's not at all possible to use the gnu11 library for windows, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in comments, although MinGW provides many GNU programs, including GCC, it does not provide the GNU C library.  C programs built by GCC for the MinGW environment rely on Microsoft's C runtime library.  They can use GNU *language* extensions, but not, generally, GNU *library* extensions that are not also implemented by Microsoft.  On the other hand, they *can* rely on Microsoft library extensions that are not implemented by GNU, though they may need to provide their own headers.

If your program relies on functions that may or may not be available in the target environment (e.g. Windows / MinGW) then the usual approach is to use conditional compilation directives and maybe macros to substitute alternatives to those functions in builds for targets that do not provide them.  Depending on the specific function, that may mean you conditionally provide your own implementation.

How you integrate conditional compilation into your build system is a much broader question.  If you are using the Autotools then facilities for this sort of thing are among its core features.  You can do similar with CMake, and probably with most other popular systems.  If you're using a hand-rolled build system then of course you have both the freedom and the obligation to come up with your own approach.